# Combine two cells in a new cell, replace all spaces with dash, and lowercase

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-docs

Trying to combine two cells in a Google spreadsheet, replace all the spaces with a "-", and lowercase everything.

Cell 1: GWG-1

Cell 2: Product Name 1

New Cell 3: gwg-1-product-name-1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your basic formula is:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-"))
```

We can concatenate two cells together to get the desired output:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A1&"-"&B1," ","-"))
```

[image]

---

Google Sheets

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This formula is dynamic in that it doesnt actually matter how many cells you decide to incluce:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(JOIN("-",A1:A2))," ","-")
```

[image]